# Does Overlayfs support upper layer to be nfs export?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, filesystems, kernel, unionfs

Does overlayfs support having upper layer as nfs mount point? I am able to have lower layer as nfs mount point but not upper? Any workaround possible?

Kernel version -> 4.4.0-21-generic

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: nope; not currently although there's a movement towards it